# Set variable appearing as 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have a sticky header that stays at the top of the page as the user scrolls down.

I want to make a script that hides the menu part of the header if the user scrolls past a certain point. I also want to make the menu reappear if the user hits the top of the screen, thus I have written this script:

```
var lastmargintop = 0;  

$(document).scroll(function() {


var margintop = $('#stickyheader').css('marginTop');
var margintop = parseInt(margintop, 10);

if(margintop > 10){
  $('#menu').hide('fast');
}

if (lastmargintop < 10){
  $('#menu').show('fast');
}

console.log(lastmargintop);
var lastmargintop = margintop;

});
```

But the variable `lastmargintop` appears as `undefined`. I am not sure why this would be. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: you realise that your if statement is hard coded to say `if(0 < 10)`? try putting `console.log` call **after** the `var lastmargintop = ...` line

Comment: @scrowler oops sorry, that was not meant to be within the function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that JavaScript variable declarations are hoisted. So even though you have `var lastmargintop` below the `console.log()`, it behaves as though the declaration part was above.

So this...

```
var lastmargintop = 0;  

$(document).scroll(function() {
    //  ...removed code...

    console.log(lastmargintop);  // expecting 0? you'll get undefined
    var lastmargintop = margintop;

});
```

Is actually interpreted as this:

```
var lastmargintop = 0;  

$(document).scroll(function() {
    var lastmargintop;

    //  ...removed code...

    console.log(lastmargintop);  // Probably clearer now why you get undefined
    lastmargintop = margintop;

});
```

Notice the `var lastmargintop` was moved to the top of the function. This happens implicitly with explicit variable declarations.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want the new value of `lastmargintop` printed to the console, than redefine it afterwards. Also, I would not define `margintop` twice like that and then call it in the definition. I would use a new variable name there.